# Asp.net web application with vb.net in codebehind VS2005

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2005

I´d like to know if there is any way to edit the codebehind of an Asp.net web application while debugging?

When I try this, a message is displayed on the status bar saying "cannot currently modify this text in the editor. It is read-only".

Answer (score 0):

The application is actually running off of a compiled version of your code. If you modify it it will have to recompile it in order for your changes to work, which means that it will need to swap out the running version for the new compiled version. This is a pretty hard problem - which is why I think Microsoft has made it impossible to do. It's more to protect you from THINKING some changes were made when they really weren't.

Comment: With C# code behind, the same situation don't happen, I can edit the codehind. I know, when i edit i need recompile.